# Como realizar um tratamento de erro eficiente em interfaces fluent?

Tags: php

Subi no Gibhub o repositório [siebel-server-manager](https://github.com/crphp/siebel-server-manager), minha proposta é criar um wrapper simples e objetivo que abstraia algumas tarefas executadas via CMD (Microsoft Windows Command Prompt).

Nessa etapa inicial a proposta se resume a uma estrutura bem simples, composta basicamente por duas classes (Client e Component). Estou com dificuldade para realizar o tratamento de erro ao chamo o método `execCommand` (em src\Component.php).

Para simular o cenário, basta ao definir a string de conexão apontar para um binário inexistente. Dentro da classe `Client` método `execCommand` tenho um tratamento que retorna um array contendo o status e a mensagem de erro, porém, devido o encadeamento da interface fluent, não consegui bolar uma estratégia eficiente para tratar o retorno e evitar que mensagens de track estourem na tela.

Agradeceria qualquer sugestão/orientação para resolução deste impasse.